# SelectedIndexChanged Event not firing under any circumstances

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

As the title says I am experiencing a problem where the SelectedIndexChanged Event of a drop down list will not fire under any circumstances.  I have spent several hours looking for the solution and trying different things. Some places suggest that this is a known bug and provide work-arounds but none of them have worked for me up until this point.

The drop down in question is built here:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    Select Project
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjects" runat="server" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This seems standard enough to me so I do not know where it could be going wrong.

EDIT (sorry I am new to this):

Code Behind:

```cs
protected void ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DashBoardImport> selectedProject = DBI.GetProject(Convert.ToInt32(ddlProjects.SelectedValue));
        foreach (var proj in selectedProject)
        {
            txtProjectName.Text = proj.ProjectName;
            this.ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = proj.Status.Equals("Current") ? 0 : 1;
            var priority = proj.Priority.PriorityName;
            if (priority.Equals("Low"))
            {
                ddlPriority.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (priority.Equals("Medium"))
            {
                ddlPriority.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }
            else if (priority.Equals("High"))
            {
                ddlPriority.SelectedIndex = 2;
            }
            //txtRank.Text = proj.ProjectRank.ToString();
            txtBusinessArea.Text = proj.BusinessArea.BusinessAreaName;
            txtRequester.Text = proj.Requestor;
        }
        //selectedIndex.Value = ddlProjects.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

There is no javascript even touching this function in anyway.  I have removed it to try and take things back to basics so to speak.  I have put break points in the page_load in the onselectedindexchanged function and in several other places and the event is never fired and the selected index is never changed from 0.

Edit2:
Here is the code several people have asked for.

```
<%@ Page Title="Future Projects" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" EnableEventValidation="true"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ITDashBoard.Web.Default" %>
```

Comment: Client-side code looks fine - can we see the code behind and the page directive of this .aspx page (to rule out namespace issues / inherits being wrong)

Comment: Could you supply more information? The ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged method! Look for javascript erros using Chrome/Firebug and let us know!

Comment: Please also show your corresponding codebehind. Maybe there's a problem with the datasource.

Comment: Please mention  how you are binding your dropdown. You should try having (!IsPostBack) in your page_load event.

Comment: @user1848739 I have tried (!IsPostBack) in several different ways as I thought that was my initial problem as well.  The dropdownlist is being bound with a simple foreach loop from a sql returned List.

Answer (score 0):

Add `AutoEventWireup="true"` to your page in given below line like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  .................. %>
```

**Edited:**  then add your own event handler

```
ddlPojects.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlPojects_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the response.  That tag is already present in the page.

Comment: check with your own event handler.

Comment: I put that in the Default.aspx.designer.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Your code behind and the .aspx code looks fine. What I suspect is a namespace issue.

Can you post up your page directive (this bit in your aspx page `<%@ Page Language="C#" .....`). Specifically I want to see the inherits attribute. I also need to the the namespace of the .cs class where `protected void ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` resides.

Have you also tried adding a break point in the ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged to see if it get hit?

Comment: I added the information that you asked for.  I have put break points all over the place and it never hits the ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged under any conditions.

Comment: So does the `ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged` Method sit in a namespace called ITDashBoard.Web and the file name is Default.aspx and the class name is Default?

Comment: Yes, sir.  That is it exactly.  I have not changed anything from what Visual Studio set it as when it was created.

Comment: And you've defiantly not copied and pasted files? The only other thing is how you're binding the database source of the dropdown. Can we see this code?

Comment: I actually ended up starting from scratch because I couldn't figure it out so I don't have the code anymore.  I appreciate all of your help though.